# Seeking suggestion for headset and bottom bracket press

Tags: tools

I'm looking for a suggestion on a single press tool, good quality, that will allow me to press fit a Praxis PF30/BB30 conversion BB and also a headset on a nice titanium frame. A single tool would be much easier on the budget.

Comment: Why not get a bike shop to do it? It isn't exactly a set of tools that you'd use frequently enough to necessarily warrant buying. That being said, while I haven't done this, Park is normally a good starting point if you want good quality tools.

Comment: I know what you're saying and, from a purely economic standpoint, it does not make sense at the moment. That said, I enjoy doing the work and have plans down the road to make some addn income from having the skills and tools on hand. Best, David

Comment: Unless you are going to be doing this to dozens of bikes, how does buying a $500 USD set of tools make more economic sense than paying a shop $50 to do it?

Comment: Is a press kit something more than stout threadded rod, a couple of large nuts, and various forms to hold the pressed items level?  I've probably got the makings lying around spare in the shed.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: @Criggie You can make a headset press using a threaded rod with some nuts and washers. I've done it - it works, but not particularly well. You have to be careful to keep the cup going in straight, since there's nothing to keep the washer from tilting to one side. The hard part is building the die (the part that presses on the cup) so that it stays perpendicular to the rod, even when you're screwing the press down. It's not impossible for a DIY project, but considering how rarely most people need to install a headset, it just isn't worth the effort.

Comment: LBS's are really suffering these days, as they get squeezed by online sales.  If you don't use them when it makes sense, they'll be gone one day when you really need them.

Comment: http://wheelsmfg.com/universal-bottom-bracket-press.html

Answer (score 3):

I've used the [Park Tools BB30 tool thing](http://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-set-for-bb30-pf30-bbt-30-3) and a bar clamp (eg [this](http://www.axminster.co.uk/axminster-trade-clamps-bar-clamp-spreader-ax945572)) to squeeze pressfit bbs in. I can't speak for headsets though.

I've found that local bike clubs are a good way of gaining access to specific tools like this. Especially as they can be expensive considering how many times you might need to use them. And you get the bonus of someone who's experienced fitting things like headsets before. People are usually keen to help a fellow cyclist out.